# Open Url & Set CookieContainer to Phone Web Browser

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 as Universal.

I use this code for set a cookieContainer to HttpWebRequest and access to my site.

```
    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    public async Task<string> Begin(string url, bool saveCookie = false)
    {
        string pageSource = "";
        HttpWebRequest request;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        //request.Method = "Get";
        if (cookieContainer != null && saveCookie)
            request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
            pageSource = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            pageSource = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(pageSource);
        }
        catch { }
        return pageSource;
    }
```

Now I have to open a url with Phone Web Browser{Internet Explorer}( forPayment page).  how can I launch a url with this CookieContainer into IE?

Also I know with this code can launch a url>

```
            var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
            options.TreatAsUntrusted = false;
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("url"), options);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you have no control over the cookies handled by IE app